# Loading resources in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I was wondering what is the best way to load yaml configuration files in symfony 2. I am talking about writing my own files and parse them to use them in my controllers.

Ideally I should be able to merge values from multiple config files representing the various environments I have in my app (dev, prod, ecc).

Let's say I have myconf.yml that looks like this:

```
name: x
surname: y
```

and myconf_dev.yml that looks like this:

```
surname: w
city: nyc
```

Ideally I would like some interface of this sort:

```
Magik::resolve("myconf", "dev");
```

which would return

```
name: x
surname: w
city: nyc
```

Sci-fi?

I spotted this http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/config/resources.html? Is it the right way to take? Or is there something better ready to use.

c
i
a
o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why inventing a new way if we [have a good one already](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html#service-parameters)?

Symfony's service container can store configuration perfectly fine and you can import external resources with [imports](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html#importing-configuration-with-imports) or [container extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html#importing-configuration-via-container-extensions).

Comment: good one mate ;) this link http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/config/resources.html puzzled me a bit but, as you pointed out, going the service way is the way. 

Cheers for that